# How can I pass an array from weaver.ini to a Pod::Weaver plugin

Tags: perl, moose, perl-pod

So it appears that in order to pass something in `weaver.ini` the plugin itself requires a Moose attribute. So if I have something like this in `weaver.ini`

```
[Acknowledgements]
contributors = 'test foo' 'foo bar'
```

I need a corresponding attribute in my plugin.

```
has contributors => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'ArrayRef[Str]',
    traits  => [ 'Array' ],
    default => sub { [ ] },
    handles => {
        contributors_count => 'count',
    },
);
```

However, I'm getting the error

```
Attribute (contributors) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'ArrayRef[Str]' with value 'test foo' 'foo bar' at /home/xenoterracide/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.1/lib/site_perl/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 1248
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've tried changing the syntax up in `weaver.ini` but that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 3):

The `.ini` syntax for that is slightly different.

```
[Acknowledgements]
contributor = test foo
contributor = foo bar
```

In addition to that, you'll have to tell `Config::MVP`, which is what takes care of `Dist::Zilla`'s config loading, that your plugin's `contributor` option may have multiple values:

```
sub mvp_multivalue_args { qw(contributors) }
```

Comment: it would appear though that something else has to change before I could call it contributors in code and contributor in config. As simply doing this results in `multiple values given for property contributor in section Acknowledgements at /home/xenoterracide/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.1/lib/site_perl/5.14.1/Config/MVP/Assembler.pm line 98`